# Counting Age median for both genders in dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function that accepts dataset, column with NaN values and grouping columns. Then it counts median value in column with NaN values and fills NaN values with that value. My problem is that when my code takes column 'Age' it should count median value for both columns 'male' and 'female' and then fill male NaN values with male median value, and the same thing for female

```
def fill_na(df, missing_value_col, grouping_col):
    values = df.groupby(grouping_col)[missing_value_col].median()
    df.set_index(grouping_col, inplace=True)
    df[missing_value_col].fillna(values, inplace=True)
    df.reset_index(grouping_col, inplace=True)

    return df

fill_na(titset, 'Age', ['Sex', 'Pclass'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you need this in a function or not, but you could do something like:

`df['Age'] = df['Age'].fillna(df.groupby('Sex')['Age'].transform('median'))`

If you wanted a function that returned a [`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html), you could do:

```
def fill_na(df, missing_value_col, grouping_col):
    df[missing_value_col] = df[missing_value_col].fillna(df.groupby(grouping_col)[missing_value_col].transform('median'))
    return df
```